# FallbackResource directive works for any URI except `/`

Tags: apache-2.2

I am using a `FallbackResource` directive to implement a front controller. Apache should redirect all requests to `index.php` in the document root, unless there is a file at the requested URI. This is exactly what it does, unless the request URI is `/`; then I get a 324 No Data Received error. Even with `LogLevel debug`, nothing is logged when this error happens.

I am using Apache 2.2.22 on Ubuntu for local development, with mod_dir enabled.

I just wanted to check if anyone can see a problem here, before I go and compile the latest Apache 2.2 and file a bug report.

Virtualhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/sites/scms/www
    ServerName scms.local
    ServerAlias www.scms.local

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/sites/scms/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride FileInfo
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        FallbackResource /index.php
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/sites/scms/www/resources/>
        FallbackResource disabled
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/sites/scms/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/sites/scms/log/access.log combined

    LogLevel debug

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. Another thing (from the docs):  
Compatibility: Apache HTTP Server 2.2.16 and later - The disabled argument is supported since 2.2.24

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I experienced same problem, so it is probably a bug.
However, I managed to solve it using "DirectoryIndex" directive:

```
DirectoryIndex /index.php
FallbackResource /index.php
```

Comment: "it is probably a bug" - FWIW, I don't think this is a bug (although the error is misleading - I would have expected a 403 Forbidden, unless `DirectoryIndex` was set to something _invalid_ in the server config?). The `DirectoryIndex` needs to be set properly for mod_dir to issue an internal subrequest for `/index.php` - this naturally occurs _before_ `FallbackResource` processes the request. Without `DirectoryIndex` being set (or not set correctly), the request is for the root _directory_ and `FallbackResource` does not apply.